# EF Core applying TOP on inner query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core to work with SQL Server.

My methods looks more or less like this:

```
public async Task<List<Entity>> GetEntities(Options queryOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var query = _databaseContext.Entities.AsQueryable();

    if (options.PropertyValueToFilterBy is not null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.Property == options.PropertyValueToFilterBy;

    if(options.InclueRelatedEntity)
        query = query.Include(x => x.RelatedProperty);

    if (options.Take.HasValue)
        query = query.Take(options.take.Value);

    return query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

EF builds a query similar to this:

```
select [list of columns] from
( 
  select top (N) *
  from Entities
  where *some condition*
)
inner join RelatedEntities on *foreign key*
```

The issue here is that `TOP` is inside inner query, so it limits records returned before joining, and joining itself can further narrow number of records.

Sometimes it happens that I get back fewer entities from the query than I specified in TOP (`Take` in C# code).

How can I force EF Core to place the top on the most outer query to make sure I always get the number of rows I want?

I tried placing `Take` method on query at the beginning and at the end of the query, but the query send to database never changes.

Generally asking - how can I gain more control on how the query is built?

Comment: EF should be performing a `LEFT JOIN` when using `.Include(x => x.RelatedProperty)`.  (I verified that behavior in EF6)   So not sure why you're seeing the `INNER JOIN` which would indeed remove rows from the final query.

Answer (score 0):

Inner join happens when EF expects there definitely to be an x for a y, for example when you're looking at children include parents:

```
context.Children.Include(c => c.Parent).Where(...).Take(...)
```

If you want a query of the form:

```
SELECT TOP 5 ...
FROM Children INNER JOIN Parents ON ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

You can OrderBy some property of the parent:

```
context.Children
  .Include(c => c.Parent)
  .Where(...)
  .OrderBy(c => c.Parent.ParentId)
  .Take(...)
```

(Take without OrderBy doesn't really make sense anyway)

If you OrderBy a property of the child you get the "top in sub query" form that is bugging you